# Laravel 5 forms && expired sessions - are there alternatives to laravel-caffeine?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

So from my experience even in laravel 5.2 the following happens:

- in the browser a page with a (ajax) form is shown
- the user does something else (e.g. goes home)
- when the user returns some time later and the session is expired, he gets an error message that the vrsf token is invalid (VerifyCsrfToken.php)
- the user is confused

So far I did not find any build-in solutions for this problem. I am using https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-caffeine but it feels a bit strange that I have to use a 3rd party lib to solve this basic issue. Maybe I missed something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use a 3rd party package for that. All it does is it add some JavaScript at the end of your page that pings the server via Ajax within a given interval in order to keep the session alive.

The CSRF-Token is part of a common security concept. But if you're sure you don't need that for your task, you can tell specific routes not to bother with it. In `/app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` you have an array where you can add the routes you want to exclude from CSRF verification:

```
/**
 * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $except = [
    //
];
```

But this might not be the best idea, because you're working around a security concept.

And this only prevents from the `TokenMismatchException` to be thrown. If the controller you're posting to still relies on an active Session, e. g. if it needs the logged in user or something, this won't help you either.

So, there are several solutions to this:

- Turn off CSRF-verification for that route. Do this if you know what you're doing and if the session doesn't matter anyway
- Hook into the `\Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException` and return a nicely formatted message to the user that their session has expired and ask them to reload the page (I guess that would be the recommended way)
- Extend the session lifetime - as @TheFallen already stated, obviously not the best idea
- Use that 3rd party package or just add that little piece of JavaScript on your own.

Comment: The point with a solution like "laravel-caffeine" (which sends "keep alive" messages) is that it is in fact not doing anything else than make the session duration infinite (the session will never expire).

That being the case, it seems to me that you could then just as well simply increase the session timeout value in your config file - much simpler and in the end I don't really see a difference - or is there still a security advantage of the "keep alive" solution?

I guess the "proper" solution then, in general, is indeed to handle the exception and show a neat message to the user.

Comment: @leo Well there is quite a difference between just increasing the session lifetime and refreshing it in order to keep it alive. If you have a very long session lifetime the session will survive browser restarts which you may not want. Or imagine that your session token gets compromised - the attacker would have respectively more time to do bad stuff. Whereas if you just ping the session periodically in order to reset the short lifetime *only while the browser is open* you won't have that issue while still maintaining a valid session for exactly as long as you need to.

Comment: Quasdunk yes I do I see your point - the big difference is indeed that "keep alive" only works with a physical browser session being there, while increasing the timeout does not guarantee anything, thereby opening the door to abuse ... that makes a big difference, point taken!

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the time of the expiration of the session. Open *config/session.php* and change **'lifetime'** to the time you wish to allow the session to be valid.

Alternatively in *Exceptions/Handler.php* listen for *VerifyCsrfToken* exception and show the user that he needs to refresh the page, login again, etc., which I think would be the better option, because increasing the session lifetime will increase the security risk.